# WPF DataGrid binding does not show values

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, expression-blend

I am a total beginner with WPF and I try to make binding to DataGrid in WPF.

XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="440" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="632">
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="420" Margin="10,10,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="603" ItemsSource="{Binding
            Source=MailCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Header="id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Header="nazwa" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Here is `MailTpl` class:

```
public class MailTpl
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And here is how I do binding:

```
public partial class WindowDataGridTest : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<MailTpl> _MailCollection =
        new ObservableCollection<MailTpl>();
    public ObservableCollection<MailTpl> MailCollection
        { get { return _MailCollection; } }

    public WindowDataGridTest()
    {
        _MailCollection.Add(new MailTpl
            { Id= "abbb", Name = "badfasdf" });
        _MailCollection.Add(new MailTpl
            { Id = "asasdfasdfdf", Name = "basdfasdfaa" });
        this.InitializeComponent();
        // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
    }
}
```

I don't know why it does not work. Any clues? Grid shows no values.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just an advice for the future.

`Visual studio` -> `Options` -> `Debugging` -> `Output Window` -> `WPF Trace Settings`.
Here you can set the level of verbosity and see important information about data binding in `Output` window. It saved me hours.

Now the reason.
You declared `MailCollection` as public property of the Window but binding is made against `DataContext` by default.

So, you have two ways:

```
this.DataContext = _MailCollection
```

And change binding a little to:

```
ItemsSource={Binding}
```

Or just change binding to this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
              AncestorType=Window}, Path=MailCollection}"
```

I also recommend this [PDF binding cheat sheet](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf). It lacks some WPF 4.5 features but still useful.

Comment: Thanks for the "Trace WPF" tip, it helped me understand my problem too!

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot write this in WindowDataGridTest() constructor.

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Comment: Thank you. I was following tutorial and it wasn't mentioned there.

Answer (score 1):

You have **not** bound the ObservableCollection to the DataGrid.

Here is the step to achieve your problem.

1. Define a name for your DataGrid. (Let's say `myDataGrid`)
2. then insert the code below in the constructor of the code behind file

   ```
   myDataGrid.DataContext = this.MailCollection;
   ```

And please look at [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) to learn more about data binding

Comment: OK. I'll thanks for your time. As I've mentioned I start working with WPF so even easy things aren't easy :)

Comment: As a new beginner of WPF, I recommend you to apply MVVM on your application. And learn about INotifyPropertyChanged, DataBinding...

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I faced then I solved it by incresing grid height.
Make sure Your Grid height is enough to show data.