# WPF Datagrid has data in the rows but not displaying text

Tags: c#, linq, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, datacontext

Maybe it's late and I have been looking at my screen for too long but this really has me stumped. I had the datagrid displaying the data but after I joined 2 tables and tried to display the data. The data is there because I am able to still get the mouse double click event to work but no text is showing in any of the columns or rows.

This is the XAML.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="ProjectsSubGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"  
          MouseDoubleClick="ProjectsSubGrid_MouseDoubleClick" 
          Initialized="ProjectsSubGrid_Initialized">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ProjectName}" Header="Project Name"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=AllottedHours}" Header="Allotted Hours"/> 
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=InvoicedHours}" Header="Invoiced Hours"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=UninvoicedHours}" Header="Uninvoiced Hours"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=RemainingHours}" Header="Remaining Hours"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and this is my C# code that is setting the DataContext.

```
private void ProjectsSubGrid_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = from p in ProjectManagement.Context.Project
               join a in ProjectManagement.Context.Account
               on p.AccountId equals a.AccountId
               select new ProjectView(){
                   AccountId = a.AccountId,
                   ProjectId = p.ProjectId,
                   ProjectName = p.ProjectName,
                   InvoicedHours = p.InvoicedHours,
                   AccountName = a.CompanyName,
                   AllottedHours = p.AllottedHours,
                   RemainingHours = p.RemainingHours,
                   UninvoicedHours = p.UninvoicedHours
               };
     ProjectsSubGrid.DataContext = list;
}
```

It works when I use the code below but as soon as I switch to the joined tables it breaks.

```
ProjectsSubGrid.DataContext = ProjectManagement.Context.Project.Where(p=>true);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use Initilized event, better do it in Window's Constructor and then check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help here.  I guess it was just me looking at the screen for too long last night.  I hadn't posted the code for the ProjectView class and that is where the problem was.

I had written

```
public class ProjectView
{
    public int ProjectId;   
    public string ProjectName;
    public int AccountId;
    public string AccountName;
    public int AllottedHours;
    public int InvoicedHours;
    public int UninvoicedHours;
    public int RemainingHours;
}
```

I fixed it by changing this to

```
public class ProjectView
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }    
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public int AllottedHours{ get; set; }
    public int InvoicedHours { get; set; }
    public int UninvoicedHours { get; set; }
    public int RemainingHours { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You should only set the `DataContext` of `DataGrid` in `LoadGrid` method.

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
{ 
    ProjectsSubGrid.DataContext = list;
}));
```

2) It does not make sense to set the Name property of `DataGridTextColumn`.
3) Update you linq query as

```
var list = (from p in ProjectManagement.Context.Project
               join a in ProjectManagement.Context.Account
               on p.AccountId equals a.AccountId
               select new ProjectView(){
                   AccountId = a.AccountId,
                   ProjectId = p.ProjectId,
                   ProjectName = p.ProjectName,
                   InvoicedHours = p.InvoicedHours,
                   AccountName = a.CompanyName,
                   AllottedHours = p.AllottedHours,
                   RemainingHours = p.RemainingHours,
                   UninvoicedHours = p.UninvoicedHours
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried refresh and updatelayout as well as calling it when initializing the page but none of it worked.  I even removed the Name property of the DataGridTextColumn and believe it or not that didn't work either.

Comment: have your commented line `ProjectsSubGrid.ItemsSource = list` from `LoadGrid` method.

Comment: Updated my answer for 1st point. Don't add the line mentioned in point 2.

Comment: that didn't work either.  I tried running it on the initialized event but that didn't work either.  If I switch the linq query back to just a single entity it works but I need some columns from a second table.

Comment: Ok. The issue seems to be linq query which should do .ToList() to fetch the records. Updated my answer, please check that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Path to your binding DataGridTextColumn statement.
Here's an example from an previous project of mine.

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Addresses}"
                                            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                            CanUserAddRows="False"
                                            IsReadOnly="True"
                                            SelectionMode="Single"
                                            IsEnabled="{Binding IsSelectionEnabled}"
                                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAddress}"
                                            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
                                            >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Street}" Header="Street"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Number}" Header="Number"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=PostalCode}" Header="PostalCode"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=City}" Header="City"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Provence}" Header="Provence"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Country}" Header="Country"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I guess something must be wrong with you DataContext and Itemsource binding. Try ItemsSource="{Binding list}" and then maybe try removing ProjectsSubGrid.DataContext = list;  It seems weird you are both binding the itemsource and the the dataContext for the grid. (edit: pressed enter way to fast).

Comment: Forgot to mention my example uses MVVM, i presume you're doing it in code behind. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761124/wpf-datagrid-binding-does-not-show-values) you can find something similar to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link.   It didn't answer my question but it did make me realize the issue.  I had forgot to use the accessors {get; set;} on the ProjectView class members.